# Performance: string "concatenado" ou todo na mesma linha?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho

Possuo um loop com milhares de resultados que renderiza uma tabela. A string está montada através do StringBuilder dessa forma(trecho de exemplo):

```
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("</select>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("<p class=\"valAnoInicio\"></p>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("</td>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("<td>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("<select class=\"cbPeriodoIniEdit\">");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("</select>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("<p class=\"valPeriodoInicio\"></p>");
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("</td>");
```

Pode haver alguma melhoria de performance caso eu coloque o código todo em uma só linha, como a seguir?

```
ScriptTbody.AppendLine("</select><p class=\"valAnoInicio\"></p></td><td><select class=\"cbPeriodoIniEdit\"></select><p class=\"valPeriodoInicio\"></p></td>");
```

E caso fosse uma concatenação, como por exemplo o código a seguir?

```
comand.CommandText  = "SELECT ";
comand.CommandText += "    TI.COD_INDICADOR, ";
comand.CommandText += "    TI.TXT_DESCRICAO, ";
comand.CommandText += "    TI.COD_PRODUTO, ";
comand.CommandText += "FROM ";
comand.CommandText += "    TB_INDICADOR TI";
```

Explicações mais avançadas sobre como a linguagem trabalha são bem vindas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O melhor sempre será manter em uma String que seja única em tempo de compilação do que em tempo de execução.

E, acredite ou não, em C# é possível usar quebras de linha em uma única String usando o caracter `@` (arroba) no início dela.

```csharp
string query =
  @"SELECT 
        TI.COD_INDICADOR,
        TI.TXT_DESCRICAO,
        TI.COD_PRODUTO, 
    FROM 
        TB_INDICADOR TI";
```

Além disso, segundo [este tópico no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283476/best-way-to-break-long-strings-in-c-sharp-source-code), se você concatenar literais String num mesmo comando, eles serão concatenados em tempo de compilação, então daria o mesmo efeito no desempenho em tempo de execução algo como:

```csharp
comand.CommandText  = 
    "SELECT " +
    "    TI.COD_INDICADOR, " +
    "    TI.TXT_DESCRICAO, " +
    "    TI.COD_PRODUTO, " +
    "FROM " +
    "    TB_INDICADOR TI";
```

Usar `StringBuilder` para concatenar literais de String irá diminuir o desempenho do programa, já que vai impedir que o compilador otimize as literais.

Por outro lado, se o compilador não puder saber o tamanho da String em tempo de compilação, por exemplo se concatenarmos variáveis, o `StringBuilder` geralmente é mais rápido do que concatenar diretamente os valores. Digo "geralmente" porque efetivamente não sei o quanto o compilador ou a CPU seriam capazes de otimizar determinados casos excepcionais.

Comment: Através do tópico mencionado cheguei a esse link (http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) com ótimas explicações, bem como você resumiu na resposta. A solução do @ é muito boa pois posso facilmente manipular o código no programa do BD e depois colar na aplicação.

Answer (score 5):

No caso de substituir várias chamadas do `StringBuilder.Append` por apenas uma, o ganho será mínimo.

Em certa ocasião, trabalhando com a classe `StringBuilder` constatei uma grande melhora na performance ao inicializar o `StringBuilder` com um tamanho suficiente para armazenar todo o resultado. Fiz isso usando duas rotinas, uma para contar o tamanho necessário, e outra para montar a string.

Para inicializar o StringBuilder com um tamanho basta passar um número inteiro no contrutor:

```
int tamanho = CalculaEspacoNecessario();
var sb = new StringBuilder(tamanho);
PreencherStringBuilder(sb);
```

Comment: **+1** Ótima dica. Inicializar a capacidade inicial de objetos com *buffer* interno (StringBuilder, List), quando se tem uma ideia do tamanho, pode melhorar muito o desempenho.

Comment: Claro que só resulta se `CalcularEspacoNecessario()` for mais rápido que os crescimetnos do `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 3):

Já foi apropriadamente dito que a melhor forma é usar uma única `string` no caso apresentado. É rápido e legível.

Mas se houver um motivo para fazer a concatenação sequencial, ela pode ser usada sem problemas de performance. Acaba virando uma única `string` em tempo de compilação. O único problema é ser menos legível.

Há otimização do compilador em muitos casos. Mas não em todos. Se todos os tamanhos das `string`s envolvidas não forem conhecidas, não há tanta otimização. Nestes casos a otimização apenas transforma as concatenações no método `concat()`. Ele certamente é melhor porque evita alocações desnecessárias, mas o cálculo do tamanho ainda é necessário.

Apesar da propriedade `SqlCommand.CommandText` ser do tipo `string`, tenho dúvidas se ela pode ser tão otimizada.

Se for útil um `StringBuilder` pode ser adequado e não ter prejuízo de performance. Pode até ser mais rápido que um método `concat()` da `string`. Quando você sabe o tamanho total necessário para todas `string`s de forma simples, possivelmente como literal constante, o `StringBuilder` é muito rápido. [Internamente](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#206408f6325aea24) ([.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Manipulation.cs,133)) o `concat()` usa um `StringBuilder` otimizado, portanto achar que que o primeiro é mais rápido que o segundo não faz sentido. Claro que em casos que tenha apenas 4 `string`s a concatenação é feita de forma mais simples sem `StringBuilder`.

Mas até agora pouca novidade foi adicionada ao que já foi dito nas outras respostas.

## Alternativa: Resources

Há casos que para facilitar o trabalho, o texto não deve estar no código. Deve estar em um arquivo externo, quando isto for pertinente, ou estar nos [Resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0). Pode ser mais fácil dar manutenção nisto e é bem rápido no segundo caso.

Para tudo existe a solução melhor aplicada. Este é um caso que a manutenção facilitada pode ser mais importante que a performance. No caso de pegar do *resource* a performance nem será muito afetada. E mesmo que seja, não criará problema para a aplicação. Esta preocupação com performance faz sentido para casos de manipulações extremas de *strings*. No caso do acesso do arquivo a performance será obviamente afetada pelo acesso a memória de massa. Mas ainda assim não vai afetar a aplicação. Claro que esta solução só deve ser escolhida quando se deseja ter a possibilidade de alterar o texto de forma fácil depois da compilação, quando se quer dar esta liberdade para o usuário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).