# Como transformar uma data em formato string sem sinais em DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

Exemplos:

```
string data = "08072013";
string hora = "1515";
```

Há algum método específico para esse tipo de formato? Tentei usar `Convert.ToDateTime()`, `DateTime.Parse`, etc. e todos me retornaram uma exception. Atualmente estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
strBuilder.Append(data).Insert(2, "/").Insert(5, "/");
strBuilder.Append(" " + hora).Insert(13, ":");
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Não utilize um `StringBuilder` para tão pouco. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7734/performance-string-concatenado-ou-todo-na-mesma-linha/21973#21973

Comment: @bigown é que vou rodar isso ai em milhares de registros.

Comment: E qual a vantagem em milhares de registros? Você mediu e viu que concatenar é mais lento? Ou você supôs?

Comment: Para te ajudar fiz um teste rápido das soluções apresentadas, incluindo a sua. Tem solução que sequer funciona e eu tive que arrumar para testar e mesmo assim o pessoal votou nela, tem solução que é o mesmo ou mais lenta que a sua. Criei uma com `concat`, eu sabia que não ia se sair bem mas ela é mais simples e não foi mais lenta que usando o `StringBuilder`. O ideal é testar em uma máquina estável, um servidor do dotNetFiddle é obviamente instável. Lembrando que o `StringBuilder` gera uma pressão violenta no GC. O `concat` não. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6hPvJ4

Comment: A única coisa que eu estou dizendo é que em casos genéricos para coisas simples é melhor usar uma simples concatenação porque a performance será essencialmente a mesma do `StringBuilder`. Em coisas mais simples ainda, a performance será melhor. Mas fica óbvio que para o caso específico seu a solução que você acertadamente aceitou é disparado a melhor.

Comment: E se você está tão preocupado com a performance poderia unificar as duas últimas linhas. Você está criando uma instância de `DateTime` que não usa em lugar algum só para sobrepor com outra instância logo na linha seguinte. Crie logo com o que você quer. Não crie algo que será descartado em seguida sem uso. O `Convert.ToDateTime(strBuilder.ToString())` já retorna um `DateTime`.

Comment: @bigown eu achei que em casos como esse, `StringBuilder` se sairia melhor, já que (em meu confuso conhecimento) uma string é imutável... e o código que eu coloquei na pergunta era apenas um teste que estava fazendo e não o código final. Tu pode me explicar ou passar algum link sobre o que é essa pressão violenta que o `StringBuilder` faz no GC? E não é que me preocupe tanto com performance, o sistema que estou fazendo é pra uso interno, meu, mas acho que é sempre legal tentar fazer da melhor forma... Obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Eu entendi, estou apenas lhe mostrando que o que parece nem sempre é verdade. Em comentários não vai dar para explicar a pressão no GC. Eu também acho que é para fazer da melhor forma, por isso eu estou te dando as dicas. Percebo que você se preocupa com isto, só falta entender algumas coisas para não se preocupar com o alvo errado. Você pensa que eu sabia que a resposta aceita era a mais rápida? Não sabia, desconfiava. Me deu curiosidade e resolvi testar para aprender isto. Ela podia ser pior. Veja como é fácil se enganar com performance http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21941/101

Comment: Não resisti, vou tentar resumir. Violenta foi um exagero. Concat simples tem performance O(1) e SB tem O(log N), é bem pior, mas claro que concat complexo é pior ainda, é O(N). O SB diminui a quantidade de alocações mas não tudo o que é possível. No fundo o concat que dá para fazer decai para o SB quando ele não é tão simples assim. Mas tem a vantagem de ser mais simples colocá-lo no código do q o SB. SB só deve ser usado quando as adições a **uma** mesma *string* ocorre em loop. É um pouco mais complicado que isto mas é o que deu em um comentário. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101

Comment: O SB pode ser usado como O(1) se você souber o tamanho total da *string* final resultante, então no seu caso dá para otimizar seu código para ser O(1) mesmo usando o SB. Mas o código ainda ficará mais complexo que usar uma simples concatenação. Simplicidade de código normalmente é preferível ainda considerando que o tempo gasto nesta conversão será ínfimo no todo que que será gasto para acessar os registros que você está falando. O resumo que eu tentei dizer desde o início é não torne seu código mais complicado para ganhar algo perto de 0,1% de performance no processamento total.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos... Teria algum artigo sobre o assunto pra me passar? Só por curiosidade mesmo...

Comment: Nada que eu consiga lembrar, estou meio enrolado esses dias. Tem os links que eu te passei que ajudam. Sobre performance, nunca suponha, sempre teste. E não faça otimização prematura, não complique o código para um ganho muito pequeno e pior, que não é necessário. Mesmo o teste pode dar a resposta errada, nem sempre é fácil entender o que testar. Eu não fiz o teste, na hora não pensei nesse caso, mas a resposta que tem `try/catch` por exemplo, pode ser **extremamente** mais lenta se as datas forem inválidas. Sem exagero, **pode** ser ordens de magnitude mais lento. Mas tem que testar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa o `DateTime.ParseExact`

Ai no seu caso ficaria

```
 string data = "08072013";
 string hora = "1515";
 data = data + hora;
 DateTime ParseData = DateTime.ParseExact(data, "ddMMyyyyHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Cara, aqui não há nenhuma sobrecarga com dois parâmetros nesse método. Ele está pedindo um terceiro parâmetro (IFormatProvider). Estou usando .NET 4.0, seria isso?

Comment: Eu fiz sem testar, mas a ideia é essa ai, atualizado.

Comment: O que é esse ultimo parâmetro?

Comment: @CaiqueC. Aqui tem mais informações sobre o último parametro http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx eu coloco assim para ele pegar indepedente da cultura que está setada. PS: Testei e funcionou direitinho.

Comment: @CaiqueC. o último parâmetro é onde você diz para o método qual cultura vai usar. Isso porque é possível usar, como segundo parâmetro, certas strings que são formatos prontos (i.e.: `"g"`) - nesse caso, é o terceiro parâmetro que define como o parser irá lidar com cada caractere. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` é uma cultura "padrão" do Framework para os casos onde nenhuma cultura real se aplica.

Comment: Perfeita resposta, parabéns!!!

Comment: @DiegoVieira fui utilizar isto só hoje... na conversão de horas entre 0 e 12, ok, a partir dai, tenho formatos de 13 á 24 e nestes me retornam um argumentexception... Seria por causa da Culture? Resolveria se alterasse para a Brasileira/ptbr?

Comment: Se não me engano HH é em 24 horas, não tem a ver coma  cultura não.

Comment: @DiegoVieira obrigado! O problema era esse mesmo, não sei porquê, mas aqui estava com os H's minúsculos. Vlw pela luz!

Answer (score 4):

Se você quiser pode criar um método de extensão com a seguinte nomenclatura:

Crie uma classe igual essa dai, com *static* e *this* fazendo referencia a um tipo *DateTime*

```
public static class Methods
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this DateTime _DateTime, string data, string hora)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}",
            data.Substring(0, 2),
            data.Substring(2, 2),
            data.Substring(4, 4),
            hora.Substring(0, 2),
            hora.Substring(2, 2)));
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        } 

    }
}
```

E usar assim:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToDateTime("08072013", "1515");
```

***Exemplo:*** [***Ideone***](https://ideone.com/p7QENj)

Comment: Eu sei que resolve o problema. Mas numa revisão de código, isso faria muita gente exclamar WTF!.

Comment: eu ainda acho mais wtf tu enviar uma data nesse formato, isso sim. Digamos que é um código mais simples para compensar a gambia da data.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(data.Substring(4, 4), 
                             Convert.ToInt32(data.Substring(2, 2),
                             Convert.ToInt32(data.Substring(0, 2), 
                             Convert.ToInt32(hora.Substring(0, 2), 
                             Convert.ToInt32(hora.Substring(2, 2));
```

Comment: Meio bruto isso, não? Olha a solução do Diego.

Comment: Resolve, não resolve?